# Connecting Multiple Database Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Need to connect Multiple database based on client.

i found some solution to switch to another database in a model as,

in User model,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  SupportBase.new.support_db_connection(self)
end
```

in SupportBase.rb

```
class SupportBase 
  def support_db_connection(model_name) 
    db_connection(model_name) 
  end

private 

  def db_connection(model_name) 
    databases = YAML::load(IO.read('config/database_support.yml'))
    model_name.establish_connection(databases[Rails.env]) 
  end 
end
```

This helps me to switch to database_support database.

But i need to dynamically change the database name.
How can i pass the database_name in User model to that method as,

```
SupportBase.new.support_db_connection(self,database_name)
```

Or is there any other way to do this.

Comment: you have tagged 3, 3.2, 4 rails versions.

Answer (score 0):

keeping the configurations at one place **database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  other stuff...

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  other stuff..

external:
.....
```

Then create a class

```
class SupportBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:external)
  self.table_name = "your_table"
end
```

Then you can access just like

```
SupportBase.first
```

I think this keeps the alternate database connection open which could be a good thing for performance as well also allows you to use AR

On dynamic: Create as many environments in database.yml, associate with a class. You will have the connection.

Check my [blog](http://imnithin.weebly.com/multiple-dbs-in-rails.html) for little more info.

**Edit**: On dynamic loading on DB, suggestion is, write the new configurations to the `database.yml` file and reload the file

Comment: Thanks for your post. In this, how we can make the database_set 'external' as dynamic based of client.

Comment: Request from [x.example.com] need to get datas from x_database, [y.example.com] need to get datas from y_database, and so on. How can I differentiate based on each request in SupportBase.rb

Answer (score 0):

Use active record.establish_connection method to switch between two DB in Rails if you have the details of the Two DB's.

Here's the code.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
 :adapter  => "postgres",
 :host     => "host",
 :username => "myuser",
 :password => "mypass",
 :database => "somedatabase"
)
```

Comment: I need to switch between n number of database based on the request.subdomain, Is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ar-octopus** gem. It will be very usefull for this scenario.